# How do I insert thousands-separators without affecting significant figures in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, microsoft-excel-2013, formatting, conditional-formatting

I need to figure out how to add thousands separators to large spreadsheets without affecting the amount of significant figures or the dates that are also in the tables. I can't figure out how to use conditional formatting to do an if/then kind of thing where it would recognize a cell that has a value ending in .?? or the like. I tried using regex in VBA but that created other issues - it's tough to get it to recognize matches because I need to format cells ending in .?? (sometimes up to .??????? and beyond) and the only way I could think of to edit that text would be to parse it out into substrings and then add commas for every three substrings - that seems really overcomplicated. Has anyone ever done something like this before/does anyone have any advice? I've spent a couple days trying to work through this in my spare time and I feel stuck and frustrated.

Comment: Seems you're overcomplicating it.  Excel has a feature to format numbers very efficiently.  Please post some sample data and describe what you've already tried and why that didn't work to help us understanding your issue.

Comment: Right click on one of the unmodified cells and select format-cell pick numeric or one of the other styles and see if you can get what you want. While there is the ability to do a range of custom formats, the standard format should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Create a range of cells you want to clean up, then try something like this.

`if instr(rng,".??") > 0 then rng.NumberFormat = "#,##0.00:-#,##0.00"`

If you want to provide a little better information about your data structure, my answer would be more specific to your problem.